# Wrap a callback method in an awaitable method

Tags: c#, error-handling, asynchronous, async-await, callback

I'm using a [.NET library](https://github.com/samjudson/flickr-net) which uses a pre-async/await type of asynchronicity. That is, it provides asynchronous (non-awaitable) method with a callback parameter.

I'm trying to write *awaitable* extension methods which will wrap some of those methods to make it easier to use with the async/await fashion but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

Here's an example of [one of those methods](https://github.com/samjudson/flickr-net/blob/160efd285dc7aafe7fe865f8be5f9019aaf124f7/FlickrNet/Flickr_OAuthAsync.cs#L15):

```
public void OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(string callbackUrl, Action<FlickrResult<OAuthRequestToken>> callback)
{
    CheckApiKey();
    string url = //...

    Dictionary<string, string> parameters = OAuthGetBasicParameters();
    // [Code to add parameters]

    FlickrResponder.GetDataResponseAsync(this, url, parameters, (r) =>
    {
        var result = new FlickrResult<OAuthRequestToken>();
        if (r.Error != null)
        {
            if (r.Error is System.Net.WebException)
            {
                var ex = new OAuthException(r.Error);
                result.Error = ex;
            }
            else
            {
                result.Error = r.Error;
            }
            callback(result);
            return;
        }
        result.Result = FlickrNet.OAuthRequestToken.ParseResponse(r.Result);
        callback(result);
    });
}
```

And here's what I came up with to provide an awaitable extension method which wraps the one above:

```
static class FlickrExtensions
{
    public static Task<OAuthRequestToken> OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(this Flickr flickr, 
                                                                    string callbackUrl)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<OAuthRequestToken>();
        flickr.OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(callbackUrl, r =>
        {
            if (r.HasError)
                tcs.TrySetException(r.Error);
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(r.Result);
        });

        return tcs.Task;
    }

    // More extension methods to be added.
}
```

**Are there any problems with my code or any downsides to this implementation?**

**Also, is there a better (more standard?) way to achieve this goal?**

Comment: Your extension method looks pretty standard for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the validation! Does that make the question off-topic or anything?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed doesn't make it off topic.  Just might not get an answer since nothing really to improve.

Answer (score 1):

### Error Handling

You are relying on `OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync` to catch all exceptions for you.

> ```
> flickr.OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(callbackUrl, r =>
> {
>     if (r.HasError)
>         tcs.TrySetException(r.Error);
>     else
>         tcs.TrySetResult(r.Result);
> });
> ```

#### Unhandled errors

However, `OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync` internally calls  `FlickrResponder.GetDataResponseAsync`, which as you can see in the [Reference Source](https://github.com/samjudson/flickrnet-experimental/blob/master/src/Internals/FlickrResponderAsync.cs) does not catch all exceptions.

Most exceptions are caught and provided to the *callback*:

> ```
> // .. snippet from FlickrNet.Internals.FlickrResponder.GetDataResponseAsync()
> if (e.Error != null)
> {
>     result.Error = e.Error;
>     callback(result);
>     return;
> }
> ```

But some are thrown to the caller:

> ```
> // .. snippet from FlickrNet.Internals.FlickrResponder.GetDataResponseAsync()
> using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
> {
>     string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
>
>     throw new OAuthException(responseData, ex);
> }
> ```

---

#### Refactored Code

To wrap this call in an async task, I would also catch these exceptions and handle them in the `Task.TrySetException`. In addition, since you provide a public API, I suggest to avoid `NullReferenceException` and check required arguments against `null`. Perhaps `callbackUrl` should also be checked early against `null`. I'm not sure about this, you'd have to verify.

```
public static Task<OAuthRequestToken> OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(
    this Flickr flickr, string callbackUrl)
{
    if (flickr == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(flickr));
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<OAuthRequestToken>();
    try
    {
        flickr.OAuthGetRequestTokenAsync(callbackUrl, r =>
        {
            if (r.HasError)
                tcs.TrySetException(r.Error);
            else
                tcs.TrySetResult(r.Result);
        });
    } 
    catch (Exception uncaughtError)
    {
        tcs.TrySetException(uncaughtError);
    }

    return tcs.Task;
}
```